# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for basic combinatorics problem...

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> How many ways are there to pick five people for a committee if there are six
>   (different) men and eight (different) women and the selection must include at
>   least one man and one woman?

I know to solve this with very basic combinatorial analysis (though I know the principle is also basic). We find the total people we can choose for the committee and proceed with cases: 1 where we have all men on the committee, 1 where we have all women on the committee and then we subtract the two cases from our total. This gives us
$${14 \choose 5} - {8 \choose 5}-{6 \choose 5}.$$

How would I compute for Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, though? I've no idea where to begin with it other drawing a venn diagram and labeling set M and W...

Comment: Your solution to the problem is correct. I don't understand what do you mean by "compute for inclusion-exclusion principle". This principle says that if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$, where $|X|$ means the number of elements in $X$. The set W="all 5-member committees with only women" and the set M="all 5-member committees with only men" are disjoint, they have no elements in common, so $|W\cap M|=0$. Perhaps you could post your Venn diagram, to clarify where the confusion lies?

Comment: lol I realized this morning that what I did was actually Inclusion-Exclusion for 2 sets where it's clear that M and W don't have any common element. I was very tired last night and had just read the chapter regarding Inclusion-Exclusion principle for 2 or 3 sets. Fatigue and first-exposure do not go hand-in-hand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more-or-less done it already.

For $i \in \{0,1,\ldots\}$, let $a_i$ be the number of committees with $\geq i$ absent genders.

We include $a_0=\binom{14}{5}$.

We exclude $a_1=\binom{8}{5}+\binom{6}{5}$.

We include $a_2=0$.

We exclude $a_3=0$.

And so on.

Comment: Thanks I realized this morning that I'd actually done it already :X Your post made me realize this further lol :)

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this is the answer:

1m and 4 w : 6 X 8C4
2m and 3 w : 6C2 X 8C3
3m and 2 w : 6C3 X 8C2
4m and 1 w : 6C4 X 8

Since these are all mutually exclusive, they can all be added.